# How can I center a component in a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, center

Here's my code, I would like to center the JTextPane in the JScrollPane:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JTextPane editor = new JTextPane();
    editor.setEditorKit(this);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(editor);
    //scroll.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.CENTER_ALIGNMENT); <<<didnt change anything, so //'ed it

    frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);

    frame.setBounds(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds());
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'center a component in a JScrollPane'? In your example `JScrollPane` is stretched to fill `JFrame`'s contentPane and `JTextPane` is stretched to fill `JScrollPane`. I can't understand what "center" in that context mean.

Answer (score 4):

The problem might be the layout of you frame  first of all you have to set size for the frame and set alignment

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer by @Mr.Cool +1

- JFrame has implemented BorderLayout by default, then code line `frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);` fills all available space into JFrame
- You have two options :

  a) Add another `JComponents` (could be empty `JPanels`) to the rest of areas `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `WEST` and `EAST`, then `JScrollPane` could be resizable with `JFrame`

  b) Use `GridBagLayout` for `JFrame` (without any `GridBagConstant`), then `JScrollPane` could not be resizable with `JFrame`